# Maple isnt executing function but prints function term

Tags: function, transpose, execution, worksheet, maple

Im using maple Im in worksheetmode I tried using Maple Input and 2D Input and I want to transpose my Matrix A:

```
 A := `<|>`(`<,>`(1, .5, -2), `<,>`(.5, 9/4+b, 5+3*b), `<,>`(-2, 5+3*b, 18+9*b+4*a));
       B:=   Transpose(A);
```

When I exectute the sheet I dont get the translated values, there are the same as the input. So my matrix looks like the same as my input matrix plus the function term.

You can see a picture in the following link: [Why arent the functions executed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0dBa.png)

Meanwhile B:=A^+ is doing it the right way and I get a transposed Matrix. But also other functions only return the function body instead the needed values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2D Input mode (the default) then the extra space you've got between `Transpose` and the bracketed `(B)` is interpreted as multiplcation. Get rid of such a space.

Also, either load the package at the start of your document like,

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
```

before calling the `Transpose` command from that package, or call it with it's full name like,

```
LinearAlgebra:-Transpose(B);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. I checked it now three times, the T*Transpose is gone. But the results of the functions still arent printed. Please check the updated fotolink in my question to see the problem. Im using Maple Input and tried also to copy the original example sheets. Curiously the same commands produce errors even so I imported the "with(LinearAlgebra)" statement. Can you please help?

Comment: The Matrix `A` in your linked image is symmetric, so of course the result from either `Transpose(A)` or `LinearAlgebra:-Transpose(A)` will appear exactly like `A`. As for your attempt, `A.shape=triangular[lower]` well that is not close to valid syntax. You likely meant `Matrix(A,shape=triangular[lower])` instead.